# dovecot + rspamd: learning ham and spam

Tags: dovecot, rspamd

I have installed my own mail server. It uses postfix, dovecot and rspamd. The delivery of emails is already working excellently, except for learning harmless and spam emails.

I found the following [instructions](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/antispam_with_sieve/#dovecot-configuration) in the dovecot documentation. There the shell script `learn-ham.sh` and `learn-spam.sh` is called by sieve, which contains the appropriate command for learning the e-mails depending on the spam service used - for example rspamd.

I have adapted the script so that simple lines are also logged in a file so that I know that it has been executed. I noticed that the script is never called.

/usr/bin/learn-ham.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set -e

LOG_FILE="/var/log/dovecot/$(basename ${0}).log"

function logInfo() {
  TIMESTAMP=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S' )
  echo "${TIMESTAMP}: INFO: ${1}"
  echo "${TIMESTAMP}: INFO: ${1}" >> "${LOG_FILE}"
}

logInfo "Start learning ham"

exec /usr/bin/rspamc --connect "localhost:11333" --password "[masked]" learn_ham

logInfo "Finished learning ham"
```

I have added `debug_log` messages to the sieve scripts. To find out whether at least the two sieve scripts are executed. I could not find corresponding log lines in the `debug.log` file.

/var/vmail/sieve/global/report-ham.sieve:

```
# Documentation:
# https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/antispam_with_sieve/#replacing-antispam-plugin-with-imapsieve

require ["vnd.dovecot.debug", "vnd.dovecot.pipe", "copy", "imapsieve", "environment", "variables"];

debug_log "Start sieve script for learning ham.";

if environment :matches "imap.mailbox" "*" {
  set "mailbox" "${1}";
}

if string "${mailbox}" "Trash" {
  stop;
}

if string "${mailbox}" "INBOX/Trash" {
  stop;
}

if environment :matches "imap.user" "*" {
  set "username" "${1}";
}

debug_log "Execute learn-ham.sh";

pipe :copy "learn-ham.sh" [ "${username}" ];
```

The instruction indicates that the sieve extension `sieve-pipe` can only be called by programs within the directory specified by `sieve_pipe_bin_dir`.

> Sieve allows you to only run scripts under sieve_pipe_bin_dir. You can’t use /usr/local/bin/my-sieve-filter.sh, you have to put the script under sieve_pipe_bin_dir and use my-sieve-filter.sh instead.

However, since `sieve_pipe_bin_dir` defines the directory in which the `sieve-pipe` program is contained, it should point to `/usr/bin`, since `sieve-filter` is also present there.

However, there is no binary `sieve-pipe` under `/usr/bin` on Arch Linux. Also `sieve-execute` is not available. Now I ask myself, where does this program come from? I could not find a `sieve-pipe` or `sieve-execute` in the official packages using `pacman --query --list | grep --perl-regexp '/usr/bin/sieve-(pipe|execute)'`.

The documentation names a unix socket. The Unix socket can of course be created later. Is this still to be defined - if so, how or where?

```
  # The directory where the program sockets are located for the
  # vnd.dovecot.pipe, vnd.dovecot.filter and vnd.dovecot.execute extension
  # respectively. The name of each unix socket contained in that directory
  # directly maps to a program-name referenced from the Sieve script.
  #sieve_pipe_socket_dir = sieve-pipe
  #sieve_filter_socket_dir = sieve-filter
  #sieve_execute_socket_dir = sieve-execute

  # The directory where the scripts are located for direct execution by the
  # vnd.dovecot.pipe, vnd.dovecot.filter and vnd.dovecot.execute extension
  # respectively. The name of each script contained in that directory
  # directly maps to a program-name referenced from the Sieve script.
  #sieve_pipe_bin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-pipe
  #sieve_filter_bin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-filter
  #sieve_execute_bin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/sieve-execute

  sieve_pipe_bin_dir = /usr/bin
  sieve_filter_bin_dir = /usr/bin
  sieve_execute_bin_dir = /usr/bin
}
```

The dovecot plugin configuration:

```
plugin {
  imapsieve_mailbox1_before = file:/var/vmail/sieve/global/report-spam.sieve
  imapsieve_mailbox1_causes = COPY
  imapsieve_mailbox1_name = Junk
  imapsieve_mailbox2_before = file:/var/vmail/sieve/global/report-ham.sieve
  imapsieve_mailbox2_causes = COPY
  imapsieve_mailbox2_from = Junk
  imapsieve_mailbox2_name = *
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_before = /var/vmail/sieve/global/main.sieve
  sieve_execute_bin_dir = /usr/bin
  sieve_filter_bin_dir = /usr/bin
  sieve_global_extensions = +vnd.dovecot.pipe +vnd.dovecot.environment
  sieve_pipe_bin_dir = /usr/bin
  sieve_plugins = sieve_imapsieve sieve_extprograms
}
```